# Application Crash when attempting to get child from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

MY application is crashing on line 43:

```
float value = dataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue(float.class);
```

When i remove the .child from the addChildEventListener and from the Datasnapshot , the app will display the float value from the database.

My aim is to display both a float value and then add in another line to display the Humidity value my database will hold.

so i will be attempting .child("temp").child("humi") to be displayed on a listview.

Can anybody steer me in the right direction or help me resolve why i cant specify child entries.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    //INITIALIZE FIREBASE DB
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    db.child("temp").limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            float value = dataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue(float.class);
            list.add("System Temperture: " + value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            adapter.clear();
            float value = dataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue(float.class);
            list.add("System Temperture: " + value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

JSON value from firebase

```
{
  "humi" : {
    "-KaxKLD00Ib97d1dRbvR" : 17.0
  },
  "temp" : {
    "-KaxKL8G17y4ezfdBMDP" : 21.0
  }
}
```

Logcat

```
01-20 18:32:18.675 16935-16935/com.m.j.project.josephmay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.m.j.project.josephmay, PID: 16935
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float java.lang.Float.floatValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.m.j.project.josephmay.MainActivity$1.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

01-20 18:32:26.645 16935-17099/com.m.j.project.josephmay W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
01-20 18:32:26.645 16935-17099/com.m.j.project.josephmay W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.m.j.project.josephmay rsrc of package com.google.android.gms

Comment: There is no child named `temp`, which leads to a NPE when you call `getValue`. Most likely you're not getting the data that you think you should be getting. As a side note, I'm quite surprised about `float.class` and would expect that to be `Float.class` (with a capital F).

Comment: I have updated my question with the JSON value

Comment: Yup, as I suspected. Use `float value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Float.class);`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am still having an issue, i have updated the JSON, how can i get the value of the child "temp"

Answer (score 0):

I think I was running into a similar issue and this response from Frank helped me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/-cdTDFBOmMw.

When you are creating the new record within Firebase, are you doing setValue() for "humi" and "temp" separately or doing setValue() for the entire object? Try switching it to setValue() for the whole object.